# convert string value in a text box into int using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have textbox that user can put either Yes or No and once they make their selection then i am writing to a table.  But before i write the value into the table i want to change it because the field takes only either 1 or 0.  I want to do the change in code behind like this:
if it is YES then change it to 1
if it is NO then change it to 0
Once it is changed then i will take the new variable and insert it in my table.  Here is my code:

```
string myvalue = ((TextBox)DV_Port.FindControl("txtmyvalue")).Text.ToString();

 sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(myvalue) VALUES(@myvalue)";                 
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@myvalue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ServerName;
```

Comment: You don't need to do this: `Text.ToString()` as `Text` is already a string.

Comment: `Text` is already _string_, you don't need to use it.

Comment: why dont you use a checkbox.

Comment: This is fairly trivial....what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments above, a checkbox would be best for this sort of input. Asking a user to type "Yes" or "No" is all very well, but how do you handle it if a user types "Maybe"? Also, you have to account for "YES" (uppercase) not evaluating to the same as "yes" (lowercase), etc etc.

If you absolutely have no choice but to use a textbox then the following should do it, but it's a bad solution to your larger problem.

```
string myvalue = ((TextBox)DV_Port.FindControl("txtmyvalue")).Text;

if (myvalue.Equals("YES", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //Change to 1
}
else if (myvalue.Equals("NO", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //Change to 0
}
else
{
    //You should probably tell the user that their input is in an incorrect
    //format here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database column which only accepts a 1 or 1 (a bit) then you should be using a corresponding UI element such as a checkbox or a radio button.

But if you have to use a textbox (for whatever reason) and you need to explicitly check for "Yes" and "No" instead of "yes" and anything other than yes:

```
bool valueIsTrue = false;
string myvalue = ((TextBox)DV_Port.FindControl("txtmyvalue")).Text;
if (myValue.ToLower() == "yes")
   valueIsTrue = true;
else if (myValue.ToLower() == "no")
   valueIsTrue = false
```

If you were using a checkbox for instance, you could simply do:

```
bool value = ((CheckBox)DV_Port.FindControl("chkMyValue")).Checked;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you can change the code, use a checkbox. A radio button or even a 2-item combobox is more acceptable. But typing yes/no? Not very friendly IMO.

To answer your question, you should use the following:

```
int myvalue = ((TextBox)DV_Port.FindControl("txtmyvalue")).Text.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert yes/no to boolean, you can use this single line:

```
bool result = (myString == "yes") ? true : false;
```

Comment: problem with this is, he's looking for "yes" or "no" not necessarily "yes" or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
string myvalue = ((TextBox)DV_Port.FindControl("txtmyvalue")).Text;
sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable(myvalue) VALUES(@myvalue)";                 
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@myvalue", SqlDbType.Bit, myValue == "Yes");
```

Pay attention to the squiggly red lines, the Visual Studio team put a lot of effort into them for you.